# How to rename tags within BODY using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

Input:

```
<ChangeRequest> /*this is xml input
    <ChangeRequestID>TEST44</ChangeRequestID> 
    <Status>          /* Need to remove this status tag
      <Name>Incomplete</Name> 
    </Status>
 </ChangeRequest>
```

I wanted to show this with `Status` tag removed and the `Name` part to be reassigned to a new attribute called `Resolve_Flag`

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Integration_Request_CR">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <CreateInterfaceRequest Destination="KISTA" CreatedBy="ONETM">
      <ChangeRequest>
        <ChangeRequestID>TEST44</ChangeRequestID>
        <Resolve_Flag>Incomplete</Resolve_Flag>       
      </ChangeRequest>
    </CreateInterfaceRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Above is the desired output

Comment: Please **edit** your question to add the input XML as well as the XSLT you're using. Please also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Thank you.